# Hibernate mappedBy="table_name" is confusing one

Tags: java, hibernate, naming-conventions

I have two domain models as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidate") // lowercase-for-database-conventions
public class Candidate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
.
.
.
@OneToOne(mappedBy="Candidate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//above here, mappedBy has Class name to map, as OO Design suggests.

private Ctc ctc;

}
```

When I try to run the application, it gives me this exception.

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.hrsystem.model.Candidate.ctc, referenced property unknown: com.hrsystem.model.Ctc.Candidate
```

But if I put the value of `mappedBy` exactly as database-convention (i.e. lower case letters as in `@Table(name="candidate")` ), it works perfectly fine.

So my question is, why we should encourage database-convention driven development though we are using Object Oriented Design?

UPDATE---

Here is my `Ctc.java` entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ctc")
public class Ctc {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private double basic;
private double hra;
private double da;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id")
private Candidate candidate;

}
```

and getters and setters below it..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not put the table name in the mappedBy, you put the name of the reference to your object.

So in your case

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="candidate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//above here, mappedBy has Class name to map, as OO Design suggests.

private Ctc ctc;
```

We would expect Ctc class to be something like that

```
public class Ctc {

//other properties
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn
 private Candidate candidate
```

Comment: do you mean class name of my entity ?

Comment: @ManojShukla I edited the answer , no the reference to your class, check the example i  put

Comment: Yes, after your edit, I added my `Ctc.java` it's exactly what you said.

Comment: if that answers your question please accept the answer

Comment: No you didn't answer my question.. my question was on value of `mappedBy`, are you getting me??

Comment: you misunderstood the mappedBy, it has nothing to do with databsse convention or the name of the table, if you change the name of your table the mappedBy will still work because it refers to the name of the attribute the relation is mapped by in the other side

Comment: See, if I put `mappedBy="candidate"` instead of `mappedBy="Candidate"` it works perfectly fine. I'm asking, why do hibernate encourages Table_name mapping here, we should be more bothered about OO design, shouldn't we??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150905/discussion-between-amer-qarabsa-and-manoj-shukla).